# DateTime in Unity as a very large number

Tags: datetime, unity-game-engine, time

I'm trying to understand a saved game file format.
The game is written with Unity.(not sure that it's related)
The file is a JSON file and the timestamp is:

```
"Timestamp": 637015624965194930,
```

This translates to Aug 16th 2019 at 14:28

another example is:

```
"Timestamp": 637014628610503310,
```

This translates to Aug 15th 2019 at 10:47

I figured that subtracting the 2 numbers will give me the difference and it kind of works.
It seems that the time is measured in 1/10000000 of a second.

Can anyone figure out how to convert this to EPOCH time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time is 1/10000000 of a second since Jan 1st 0001

It is the standard time format used by .NET

so you can subtract 621355968000000000 (Jan 1st 1970) and divide by 10000000 to get seconds since EPOCH.

Comment: Wow - I've been coding so long and even in .Net and missed that.